# PK systems using groups in practice

Tags: rsa, public-key

The four  Public-key cryptosystems: RSA, ElGamel, DH, and Rabin (all with others) all require some group operations in an  integer field or multiplication group of some residue classes. When it comes to encrypting blocks of bits in binary how are these public key cryptosystems performed ? Are byte blocks just converted to base 10 and the encryption is perform on each byte? However results of RSA are much longer than a byte each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are [used to encrypt symmetric keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). ​ No.

Comment: The symmetric key is obviously encoded in someway, probably hex or binary, so how are these public key operations performed on something in that format, the examples I see are on base 10 only? Is it just left in hex or binary?

Comment: @dylan7 hex, binary, and decimal are all just different ways of viewing the same number, the key is treated as a series of bits, and the mathematical operations are performed on those bits